# Как можно надёжно зашифровать тело http-запроса?

Tags: android, безопасность, admob, криптография

**Задача:**
С помощью шифрования максимально усложнить подделку http-запроса.

**В наличии:**
Имеется сервер, куда будет приходить входящий запрос, имеется мобильное приложение на android, которое будет отправлять запрос, на мобильном приложении подключена рекламная сеть AdMob.

**Подробно:**
На сервере есть база, в которой есть компании, у каждой компании есть поле "Срок действия премиум", в мобильном приложении за просмотр рекламного видеоролика будет вознаграждение +2 дня премиум для компании, которую пользователь открыл в мобильном приложении.

**Проблема:**
Знающий человек сможет увидеть исходящий запрос от мобильного приложения, увидит куда и с какими параметрами и сможет для любой компаний продлить премиум на любой период.
Пример запроса: POST http://example.com/increase-period BODY "{companyId: 123}"

**Детали проблемы:**

- AdMob не имеет функции "reward callback url".
- В системе нет пользователей, в мобильном приложении нет авторизации, имеется только ip адрес отправителя запроса.

Поэтому предо мной стоит задача обхитрить потенциального мошенника и/или хотя бы максимально усложнить ему задачу, чтобы халявное продление премиума не шло на потоке и можно было быстро это пресечь, изменив алгоритм шифрования например.
Возможно я чего-то не знаю о AdMob, но посмотрев документацию я не обнаружил того, что мне требуется.

**Пока что я додумался только до такой конструкции:**
В мобильном приложении тело исходящего запроса будет шифроваться алгоримом RSA с секретной фразой, а на сервере будет дешифроваться по той же фразе.
Но есть проблема - мобильное приложение можно декомпилировать и узнать алгоритм шифрования. По этой теме я немного почитал, говорят от этого никак не уберечься, можно лишь усложнить тем, что разбросать это шифрование по разным классам и сделать более запутанным, это отпугнёт незатейливых взломщиков.

К сожалению AdMob не предоставляет никаких уникальных данных или идентификаторов, которые могли бы помочь определить, был ли осуществлён просмотр рекламы.

В голове крутятся мысли о том, что нужно как-то использовать сервер для решения этой задачи, но не могу определить стратегию.
Из минимума на сервере можно сделать ограничение запросов по IP адресу, но ведь есть прокси... Ещё можно добавить общее разумное ограничение количества продлений для одной компании за промежуток времени.

Поэтому вопрос ко всезнающим, возможно вы сталкивались с такой задачей?

Comment: Как по мне, лучше всего использовать сокеты

Comment: Используйте HTTPS

Comment: @mit делаем свой сертификат, добавляем его в доверенные на андроиде, ставим прокси и успешно перехватываем запрос

Comment: @andreymal приложение может и не использовать системное хранилище для определения достоверности, зашив отпечаток нужного ключа в исходники. Так приложение даже сможет определить, когда его пытаются надуть. Такое только реверс-инжиниринг пробьёт, но он пробьёт любые чисто клиентские меры по защите, так что...

Comment: @D-side +1, называется certificate pinning. шьется вся цепочка сертификатов, не сами сертификаты конечно, их хэши. http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/CertificatePinner.html

Answer (score 1):

Несколько раз всё перечитал и пришёл к выводу, что задача сводится к тому, чтобы сделать невозможным воспроизведение исходного кода приложения, что конечно тяжело сделать простому разработчику.
Существуют сервисы типа [Stringer](https://jfxstore.com/stringer/) и [DexGuard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/dexguard), которые, скорее всего за огромную плату(даже не написано сколько), могут добавить брони для исходников.

Так что я решил пока просто шифровать тело запроса простым алгоритмом с секретной фразой, и немного запутать это в исходниках.
Когда и если начнут взламывать - тогда уже и буду реагировать :)

Answer (score -5):

Сделайте отправку запроса (и само шифрование и прочее, что нужно защитить) на C++ (NDK, JNI). От незатейливых взломщиков поможет, от меня нет

А вообще, просмотрами действительно должен заниматься сервер. Делаете запрос к тому что просматриваете - а сервер не только отдает вам просматриваемое, но и записывает просмотр у себя. Делаете еще раз с того же IP - а он уже записан. И т.д. Но с AdMob дел не имел, и в суть вникать не хочу